# Regular expressions for making uppercase accented letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to make a replacement like this
from arouzière to AROUZIÈRE.

I use notepad++ 6.6.7 for this in the following manner:

search: (\p{L}*?)
replace: \U\1\E

Problem:
The result is AROUZIèRE.
As you can see the accented letter is not made UPPERCASE.
Do you know a workaround or even if this is possible via RegEx with notepad++?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Is it that you **need** regex? Because Notepad++ can do this OOTB with Ctrl+Shift+U

Comment: Thanks for the replay,
I was not very clear in my initial stament.
I have an html file tagged with elements like this <span class="allcaps">arouzière</span>, <span class="allcaps">mécourt</span> ... etc. and I need to automate this uppercase procedure and i thought of regex that works just fine for "regular" letter but misses the accented letter.

Comment: Do you consider recording a macro for that? What kind of automation do you want to get?

Comment: I just wanted to search and replace all of the instances. But probably regex in notepad++ cannot help me with that because it cannot make uppercase letters that have accents like: from é to É, or ü to Ü  etc. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern

```
(\p{Ll})
```

Which find lowercase letters that have an uppercase variant.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF5kY9/1)

Note that some unicode characters do not have an uppercase variant.